# How to create a live video stream server using WebRTC and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I'm working on a project live video streaming using OBS. Now I have to create a new method to live video streaming using WebRTC and save the video to the server. Any idea to do that? Thanks!

```
                                         / --> WebRTC Client 1
 WebRTC Capture ---\       NODEJS       / --> WebRTC Client 2
 WebRTC Capture ---->      Server      | ---> WebRTC Client ...
 WebRTC Capture ---/                    \ --> WebRTC Client 20
                                         \ --> WebRTC Client 21
```